# Selecting elements of specific geometry type in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, sql, geometry

I was reading a postgis tutorial and noticed that unlike working with shapefiles, one can actually store different types of geometry in postgres. In a table created with multiple geometry types, the tutorial used:

```
SELECT ST_X(geom), ST_Y(geom)
  FROM geometries
  WHERE name = 'Point';
```

to show X, Y coordinates of a point. I was wondering in general, whether we can use the geometry type in the `WHERE` clause to do the same. I tried:

```
SELECT ST_X(geom), ST_Y(geom), name
  FROM geometries
  WHERE ST_geometrytype(geom) = ST_Point;
```

and got:

```
ERROR:  column "st_point" does not exist
LINE 3:   WHERE ST_geometrytype(geom) = ST_Point;
                                        ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: column "st_point" does not exist
SQL state: 42703
Character: 87
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: The operator is defined as returning type `text`. You'll need to quote your equivalence value `WHERE ST_geometrytype(geom) = 'ST_Point'`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your Line ...

```
WHERE ST_geometrytype(geom) = ST_Point;
```

Indicates that ST_Point is a column since it is not in quotes. I see here also a comment from @Vince that is saying basically the same thing that I am. Since ST_Point is not quoted in your expression is is trying to evaluate what is in ST_geometrytype(geom) against another field/column and it can't find a column by that name. Just change the line I quoted above to ...

```
WHERE ST_geometrytype(geom) = 'ST_Point';
```

Comment: thanks for the addition regarding the return Object is a string. see also Postgis-definition: [PostGIS docs for ST_GeometryType](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeometryType.html)